# how can I show that a Function is Bilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I have to Show, if a function $f(u,v)=1+3x_{1}-2y_{2}$ is Bilinear.  $u^T =(x_{1},x_{2})  v^T =(y_{1},y_{2}) $ I know, that I have to prove

$
⟨ v , w 1 + w 2 ⟩ = ⟨ v , w 1 ⟩ + ⟨ v , w 2 ⟩ \\ {\displaystyle \langle v,w_{1}+w_{2}\rangle =\langle v,w_{1}\rangle +\langle v,w_{2}\rangle } 
,\\
⟨ λ v , w ⟩ = λ ⟨ v , w ⟩ {\displaystyle \langle \lambda v,w\rangle =\lambda \langle v,w\rangle } 
,\\
⟨ v , w λ ⟩ = ⟨ v , w ⟩ λ {\displaystyle \langle v,w\lambda \rangle =\langle v,w\rangle \lambda } 
.$ \

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: How? Substitute the specific function that you have into those equations and see if they hold. I’d suggest trying one of the latter part of the set, since the presence of a constant term is a big hint that you can’t factor out $\lambda$ as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ is not bilinear. Why? Take $u^T=(1,1)$, ${v_1}^{T}=(1,1)$ and ${v_2}^{T}=(1,1)$, then

$$f(u,v_1+v_2)=f((1,1),(2,2))=1+3(1)-2(2)=0$$ and on the other hand,

$$f(u,v_1)+f(u,v_2)=f((1,1),(1,1))+f((1,1),(1,1))=2+2=4$$